# Copy paste to new Worksheet in Excel

Tags: excel, copy-paste, worksheet-function, vba

So i got this code wich copies cells from C4 to C10 and pastes them. The problem is that it pastes to the same worksheet and i need to paste it to second worksheet.

I have no idea how to change worksheets in code so i hope someone can help me out.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Save_Click()
Range("C4:C10").Copy
Dim curRange As Range
Dim curCol As Integer: curCol = 7
Dim completed As Boolean: completed = False
Do
    curCol = curCol + 1
    Set curRange = Range(Cells(3, curCol), Cells(9, curCol))
```

If (WorksheetFunction.CountA(curRange) = 0) Then
   Exit Do
End If
Loop While (Not completed)

curRange.PasteSpecial
End Sub

Comment: Do you literally just want to paste the values in one sheet (C4:C10) into another sheet or is there anything more to this? Is the loop in the middle intended to find the next available unused column? Presumably this should be checking the sheet that you are pasting too?

Comment: I told you: just add the sheet name to range. If the original worksheet is "sheet1", Range("C4:C10") is the same than Sheets("sheet1").Range("C4:C10"). If the destination range is in "sheet2", you can  Set curRange = Sheets("sheet2").Range(Cells(3, curCol), Cells(9, curCol))

Comment: You should always include the Sheets("sheet name") heading part while dealing with different worksheets. Range("C4:C10") is a short-form of Sheets("sheet1").Range("C4:C10") and might be confusing while dealing with different sheets (not sure if the active sheet is sheet1 or sheet2). Feel free to ask more if this is not clear. You should have asked me again in the previous question if you didn't understand my point; I thought that it was clear to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the worksheet "Iskalnik", as you have done, use:

```
Sheets("Iskalnik").Range("C4:C10").Copy
```

For the worksheet "Baza", instead of this:

```
Set curRange = Sheets("Baza").Range(Cells(3, curCol), Cells(9, curCol))
```

use this:

```
With Worksheets("Baza")
    Set curRange = .Range(.Cells(3, curCol), .Cells(9, curCol))
End With
```

The issue with curRange is that the `Range` and `Cells` keywords all need to reference the sheet. The `With ... End With` is just a convenient way to do that.

Comment: Thank you i was trying to do this for so long that i gave up. Thank god i saw your comment so i can go back to my project.